# I seem to have made an enemy

Tags: discussion

Somebody has gone through all my answers, systematically downvoting every one. I think I know who it is, but I wonder what to do about it. Any suggestions?

**Edit** My reputation has now been restored, whether by humans or robots I can't tell.

Comment: Why not just tell the moderators? That's what they're here for.

Comment: I thought maybe the moderators might read my post, user1736.

Comment: Dang, now they've downvoted this one.

Comment: No idea why one would downvote this question. Being stalked could be disconcerting. +1.

Comment: @Moron: because it doesn't belong on the main site?

Comment: @Qiacho: Do downvotes carry over with migration? I was under the impression they didn't, I might be mistaken, though... Seems like we are on meta, even though we clicked on it from the main site!

Comment: @Moron:  I guess so.  The original downvote was before migration.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Seems to be a strange feature. The -1 was for being off-topic, and it is now born on-topic with -1. Given that most migrations are due to being off-topic, seems like most questions will start out with negative votes on the on-topic site. Also, how does the system deal with the rep imbalance? Anyway...

Comment: I thought the -1 was for being me. (I assumed it was the same user.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The offending user has been suspended for a day and I am sending them an email now.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the downvotes? Clearly the suspension indicates that their actions are not acceptable.

Comment: ("Clearly", I say, without knowing. Anyway, I think the downvotes should be removed.)

Comment: @ANdres: If the downvotes hit the anomaly checker, they will automatically be removed. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thank you! I have been especially impressed here by two users who have come to my support despite previous run-ins with me.

Comment: @Andres: I don't think I can remove the downvotes, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Said user could go through and remove those down votes.  It would be a touch of class IMHO.  Of course a down vote is legitimate if an answer is believed clearly incorrect.  Down votes penalize the caster as well, so this serial behavior reminds me of http://www.jstor.org/pss/20076295 an experiment by Zizzo and Oswald (2001).

Comment: @hardmath: not if the window for changing votes has passed.

Answer (score 9):

The daily voting anomaly script will remove any statistically anomalous voting patterns it discovers.

This happens every 24 hours and requires no intervention.

Comment: It checks *that day* or does it check previous days? If not, and if the downvoter downvoted only once every day, then they would probably remain undetected.

Comment: @muntoo that's indistinguishable from regular activity, then. If you buy enough pseudoephedrine containing products, one per day, at the end of 365 days you can make meth..

Comment: True (about the meth part), but if this doesn't take too much CPU, you could check how many times [over a week] user A has downvoted user B, and if user B has received more upvotes or downvotes by OTHER users (C, D, etc). If downvotes > upvotes user A is innocent else, flag him for further processing. Of course, you only check it at downvotes, not serial upvoting :).